# Android onEditorAction force close

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to perform some functions once the user presses "Next" on their keyboard but I'm having some issues. The app compiles, but crashes once "Next" is pressed.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText etGhs = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etGhs);

    // Calculate DGM once the user has finished typing
    etGhs.setOnEditorActionListener(
            new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH ||
                            actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE ||
                            event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN &&
                                    event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                        if (!event.isShiftPressed()) {
                            // the user is done typing.
                            // get string from etGhs
                            double ghs = Integer.parseInt(etGhs.getText().toString());
                            double dgm = ghs * 0.000064179; // calculate avg DGM

                            setDgmAndDailyBtc(dgm);
                            return true; // consume.
                        }
                    }
                    return false; // pass on to other listeners.
                }
            });
}
```

Here is the logcat

```
03-11 20:51:09.847  11528-11528/com.devinshoe.bitcoinprofit.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.devinshoe.bitcoinprofit.app, PID: 11528
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.KeyEvent.getAction()' on a null object reference
        at com.devinshoe.bitcoinprofit.app.MainActivity$1.onEditorAction(MainActivity.java:27)
        at android.widget.TextView.onEditorAction(TextView.java:4236)
        at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.performEditorAction(EditableInputConnection.java:138)
        at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:297)
        at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:77)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

An old question, but if you are still looking for an answer, the following has worked for me. The part where you check for "Enter" options, i.e.

```
if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH ||
                            actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE ||
                            event.getAction().....
```

You need to add more search options, i.e.

```
if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH ||
                            actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE ||
                            actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO ||
                            actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT ||
                            event.getAction().....
```

My keyboard was setup to take the default action as IME_ACTION_GO, but just to be on a safer side, I left the other options in there.

Answer (score -1):

event is null.  You need to check for that and not call getAction on it